How can I stop C-x TAB adding tabs rather than spaces?
I use C-x TAB to indent my code by four spaces. I do this with the arrow keys. When I am done, it has added a tab rather than four spaces. How can I prevent this? C-u 4 C-x TAB does the same.

This question is similar to: Make web-mode always indent with spaces. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

(setq indent-tabs-mode nil) as documented here

By default, Emacs inserts tabs in place of multiple spaces when it formats a region. (For example, you might indent many lines of text all at once with the indent-region command.)

